# Azure devops extension- Custom extension point

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

What should i target in the manifest file in order to display my extension in the same level than Azure Boards-Repos-Pipeline etc...[image]

I was able to display it under all existing hubs but when it comes to new ones i'm not able to find anything in Microsoft documentation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops](https://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is not supported to add a custom hub to the top-level that is same as the hub groups (such as **`Boards`**, **`Repos`**, **`Pipelines`**, etc..) in the menu bar of project. You can only add child hubs under the top-level hub groups.

---

If the custom hub you want to add does not belong to any of the services (**`Boards`**, **`Repos`**, **`Pipelines`**, **`Test Plans`** and **`Artifacts`**), as a workaround, you can add it as a child hub under **`Overview`**.

The **`Overview`** also is a top-level hub group in the menu bar of project. Every time when opening a project from the home page of organization, by default, it will expand **`Overview`** and open the child hub **`Summary`**.

To add a custom hub under **`Overview`**, in the **`vss-extension.json`** file, you need to set the '**`targets`**' of this custom hub to be '**`ms.vss-web.home-hub-group`**'.

See below example:

- Menu bar of project.

  [image]
- The **`vss-extension.json`** file. More details, see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/contributions-guide/vss-extension.json#L506-L518).

  [image]

---

If you really need the feature to add a custom hub or hub group to the top-level in the menu bar of project, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). This will make it more convenient for the product teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

---

**EDIT:**

Here I find the documentation ([**Add a hub group**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-hub-group?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops)) to add a custom hub group to the top-level in the menu bar, and also add a custom hub to the custom hub group.

For your case, another workaround is you can add a custom hub group to the project menu bar, then add the custom hub to it.

---

Comment: @YassGr, I have updated my above answer with another workaround (see **EDIT**). Check and try it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working. I just followed the steps in the link you provided.

Comment: @YassGr, You're welcome. If the answer is helpful for you, maybe, you can accept it as the solution of this case. This could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar questions.